# Needing multiple counts on a Terraform resource?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-efs

I have the following Terraform resource which is intended to create a separate encrypted EFS volume per warehouse, and then create mount targets in two subnets for each:

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "efs-data-share" {
  count      = "${length(var.warehouses)}"
  encrypted  = "${var.encrypted}"
  kms_key_id = "${element(data.aws_kms_key.encryption_key.*.arn,count.index)}"
  performance_mode = "${var.performance_mode}"

  tags {
    Name        = "${element(split(".",var.warehouses[count.index]),0)}-${var.name_suffix}"
    Warehouse   = "${element(split(".",var.warehouses[count.index]),0)}"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
    Purpose  = "${var.purpose}"
  }
}

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "mounts" {
  count           = "${length(var.subnets)}"
  file_system_id  = "${aws_efs_file_system.efs-data-share.*.id}"
  subnet_id       = "${element(var.subnets, count.index)}"
  security_groups = ["${var.efs_security_groups}"]
}

data "aws_kms_key" "encryption_key" {
  count = "${length(var.warehouses)}"
  key_id = "alias/${element(split(".",var.warehouses[count.index]),0)}-${var.key_alias_suffix}"
}
```

The EFS themselves launch fine, but the mounts fail, because the file_system_id must be a single resource, not a list.

```
    * module.prod_multi_efs.aws_efs_mount_target.mounts[1]: file_system_id must be a single value, not a list
    * module.prod_multi_efs.aws_efs_mount_target.mounts[0]: file_system_id must be a single value, not a list
```

I'm not sure what my recourse is here in terms of Terraform syntax. I need two mounts in each case, so my count is on the length of the subnets variable, for which I'm passing in subnet-123456 and subnet-567890. How can I get the system to make both mounts for each EFS made (seven in total by length of warehouses list) without being able to use a second count within the aws_efs_mount_target?

Here is how I am calling the module:

```
module "prod_multi_efs" {
  source              = "../../../../Modules/Datastore/MultiEFS"
  efs_security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.prod-efs-group.id}"]
  environment         = "Prod"
  name_suffix         = "${module.static_variables.prod_efs_name}"
  key_alias_suffix    = "prod-efs-${module.static_variables.account_id}-us-east-1"
  subnets             = ["${module.prod_private_subnet_1.subnet_id}", "${module.prod_private_subnet_2.subnet_id}"]
  warehouses          = "${module.static_variables.warehouses}" #The list of seven warehouses
}
```

Here is my plan with the attempt of adding [count.index] as per the answer below - it does two mounts, but only to the first 2 of the 7 FS IDs:

```
  + module.stg_multi_efs.aws_efs_mount_target.mounts[0]
      id:                                      <computed>
      dns_name:                                <computed>
      file_system_arn:                         <computed>
      file_system_id:                          "fs-123456"
      ip_address:                              <computed>
      network_interface_id:                    <computed>
      security_groups.#:                       "1"
      security_groups.4286231943:              "sg-xxxxxxxxxx"
      subnet_id:                               "subnet-aaaaaaaa"

  + module.stg_multi_efs.aws_efs_mount_target.mounts[1]
      id:                                      <computed>
      dns_name:                                <computed>
      file_system_arn:                         <computed>
      file_system_id:                          "fs-567890"
      ip_address:                              <computed>
      network_interface_id:                    <computed>
      security_groups.#:                       "1"
      security_groups.4286231943:              "sg-xxxxxxxxxxx"
      subnet_id:                               "subnet-bbbbbbbbbb"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Terraform 0.12 introduced a new function `setproduct` for situations like this where you need a set of objects representing every combination of elements from two or more collections:

```
locals {
  data_share_subnets = [
    for pair in setproduct(aws_efs_file_system.efs-data-share, var.subnets) : {
      file_system_id = pair[0].id
      subnet_id      = pair[1]
    }
  ]
}
```

The above declares `local.data_share_subnets` as a data structure something like this:

```
[
  {"file_system_id": "fs-123456", "subnet_id": "subnet-aaaaaaaa"},
  {"file_system_id": "fs-123456", "subnet_id": "subnet-bbbbbbbb"}
  {"file_system_id": "fs-567890", "subnet_id": "subnet-aaaaaaaa"},
  {"file_system_id": "fs-567890", "subnet_id": "subnet-bbbbbbbb"}
]
```

You can then use that with the new `for_each` feature introduced in 0.12.6 to declare one `aws_efs_mount_target` instance per entry in that collection:

```
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "mounts" {
  for_each = { for o in local.data_share_subnets : "${o.file_system_id}:${o.subnet_id}" => o }

  file_system_id  = each.value.file_system_id
  subnet_id       = each.value.subnet_id
  security_groups = var.efs_security_groups
}
```

The `for` expression in the `for_each` argument transforms the list shown above into a map whose keys are like `"fs-123456:subnet-aaaaaaaa"`. Terraform will then track these instances using addresses like this:

- `aws_efs_mount_target.mounts["fs-123456:subnet-aaaaaaaa"]`
- `aws_efs_mount_target.mounts["fs-123456:subnet-bbbbbbbb"]`

...which means you can safely add and remove individual filesystems and subnets without disturbing any other unrelated mount target instances. (that would not be true using `count`, because the instances would be identified by their positions in the list.)

There is no direct equivalent of the above in Terraform 0.11 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If I do this , I get the following error 
The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on."